# How to skip line using RegEX

Tags: java, regex

I want to skip some line from a file if the line contains specific word.

My input is:

```
Report ID: XYZ
Report Date: 8/1/2015
Address : Hello 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
SNO Name    Age
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1   Shyam   28
2   Ram     30
```

The output should be:

```
Report ID: XYZ
Report Date: 8/1/2015
Address : Hello 
1   Shyam   28
2   Ram     30
```

I have tried

```
.*[^--|BAT]*
```

but I'm not getting appropriate output.

**Note: I am using RegExHTML in Firefox for parsing.** 
Sorry for mention in JAVA.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What regex tool are you using?

Comment: Which language are you running?

Answer (score 1):

```
-+[\s\S]*?-+
```

Use replace instead and replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/31

Use

```
-+[\\s\\S]*?-+
```

in case of java

Answer (score 0):

Use dotall modifier `(?s)` to make dot in your regex to match even line breaks.

```
String s = "Report ID: XYZ\n" + 
            "Report Date: 8/1/2015\n" + 
            "Address : Hello \n" + 
            "--------------------------------------------------------------------\n" + 
            "SNO Name    Age\n" + 
            "--------------------------------------------------------------------\n" + 
            "1   Shyam   28\n" + 
            "2   Ram     30";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?s)(?<=\n|^)-+.*?-\n",""));
```

Output:

```
Report ID: XYZ
Report Date: 8/1/2015
Address : Hello 
1   Shyam   28
2   Ram     30
```